# Reading input type="hidden" with jersey

Tags: java, html, google-app-engine, jsp, jersey

..
Hi,

I have in .jsp page an input hidden like this:

```
<form ... method="post">
  ...
  <input type="hidden" name="tc" value="true"/>
  ...
</form>
```

And in the server side (all in GAE), the java code is like this...

```
@POST
@Path("after")
public Response afterTC(
                    ...
        @FormParam("tc") boolean tc
                    ...
) throws URISyntaxException {
        return Response.ok("OK!").build();
}
```

The method get called perfectly but... when debugging and trying to recover the tc value... it's always false... How can I get the correct tc value? Don't know how to do it =(

Thanks!

Comment: Try plain String instead of boolean.

Comment: That couldn't help me... but thanks... Anyone? :(

Comment: what do you mean? Was correct value present in @FormParam("tc") String tc?

Comment: No no, it wasn't... and I don't know why... It's always false...

Answer (score 3):

Your example code works for me (that is, I put together basically the same thing, and tc is true).

I'm sure that the problem is NOT that the input type is hidden -- from the perspective of your handling code, a hidden input looks exactly the same as any other form input. They all get sent through as just a string name and a string value... in this case, with the value getting converted to boolean behind the scenes.

What I would do in your case is like Pavel suggested -- try `@FormParam("tc") String tc` and determine what string value is coming through. This is just a debugging technique; once you figure out what's going wrong and fix it, you can switch it back to a boolean.

If it were me, my first guess would be a typo -- if the input's "name" is not identical to what you give FormParam, it would come out as false.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Boolean instead of boolean? Boolean should work in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you're not submitting the form containing this `<input>`?

What I mean is if you have something like this:

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="tc" value="true"/>
</form>
<form>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

There's two different forms, and only the second one (without the "tc" input) is submitted.